# matplotlib negative numbers on tick labels displayed as boxes

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I'm using matplotlib to generate plots for a report and specifying my own style sheet to specify text formatting to comply with a specified document style for a report. In my .mplstyle stylesheet I'm specifying the font family as follows:

font.family : Tw Cen MT

This works fine so far for everything except when I have tick labels with negative numbers. For negative numbers on the tick labels the minus sign gets displayed as a box with this font. With the default font family it works correctly, but I need to use the Tw Cen MT font family.

Is there a way to use the Tw Cen MT font family in a way that correctly displays negative numbers?

Alternatively, is there a way to specify a different font just for the tick labels.

In my Python script I'm setting the ticks as follows:
ax2.set_yticks([-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3], minor=False)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font you are using possibly does not have the unicode minus sign implemented.
While i would strongly recomment not to use a font without basic unicode signs, you may get around this problem by using a [normal hyphen instead](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/unicode_minus.html).

In your mplstyle file add the line

```
axes.unicode_minus  : False
```

or use

```
plt.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False
```

as in the linked example.

Comment: I added the line to the mplstyle file and that fixed the issue. Thanks for the help.